# Error determining IP Addresses for unbouncepages.com/testpage20171/

Tags: java, html, windows, networking, ip

I have created this test landing page `unbouncepages.com/testpage20171/`.

However, it is not resolving to an ip address.

The error I get is (at https://www.site24x7.com)

> Error determining IP Addresses for unbouncepages.com/testpage20171/

Currently I have a website (xyz.com). I want to create `landing.xyz.com` which will point to this landing page. This is not possible since website is not resolving to an ip address.

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

A simple ping command of the domain holding your page will help. unbouncepages.com/testpage20171/ is not a subdomain so it should be hosted on the same server as unbouncepages.com

```
C:\>ping unbouncepages.com

Pinging unbouncepages.com [52.76.110.124] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```